# undefined control sequence \definecolor

Tags: errors

I added `\definecolor{bg}{HTML}{282828}` to my `.tex` file and now `latex --shell-escape file.tex` is breaking with less-than-helpful error messages.

`File.tex` looks like:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=40cm,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{solarized}
\definecolor{bg}{HTML}{282828}

\begin{document}
\begin{LARGE}
  \inputminted{filetype}{example}
\end{LARGE}
\end{document}
```

(note my shell script changes `{filetype}` and `{example}` to appropriate values)

The error message says

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \definecolor
                {bg}{HTML}{282828}
?

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

But as you can see `\begin{document}` is not actually missing.

I see lots of other questions about "undefined control sequence" but don't understand what it's actually about nor what it means in this context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An "undefined control sequence" means you're using a control sequence (or macro) that doesn't exist. `\definecolor` is defined within the [`color` package](//ctan.org/pkg/color). It's included when using [`xcolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor). So, add `\usepackage{xcolor}` to your preamble before using `\definecolor`:

```
%...
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{HTML}{282828}
%...
```

Comment: "*Control sequence* is (typically, roughly speaking) a sequence of letters with preceded backslash" from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242053/what-is-a-control-sequence